# Php DateTime and timestamp calculation

Tags: php, algorithm, datetime, math, for-loop

I'm trying to get an array of dates to populate a calendar and I'm facing an the issue of infinite loop.

Here is the code:

```
$month_length = 1;
$day_begin = 9;
$day_end = 19;
$event_interval = 15;

$date = new DateTime();

$today_date_name = $date->format("D");
$today_date_number = $date->format("j");
$today_date_month = $date->format("M");
$today_date_month_number =$date->format("n");
$today_date_year = $date->format("Y");


for ($length = 0; $length <= ($month_length - 1); $length++)
{
    $date->modify("+$length month"); 
    $current_date_name = $date->format("D");
    $current_date_number = $date->format("j");
    $current_date_month = $date->format("M");
    $current_date_month_number = $date->format("n");
    $current_date_year = $date->format("Y");

    //calculate the length of the month
    $current_month_length = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $current_date_month_number, $current_date_year);

    if($current_date_month_number != $today_date_month_number){
        // if we are not in the current month, start the second loop
        // the first of the month.
        $current_date_number = 1;
    }

    for($current_date_number; $current_date_number <= $current_month_length; $current_date_number++)
    {
        $date->setDate($current_date_year, $current_date_month_number, $current_date_number);

        //set the ending before because of the loop;

        //set the ending of the day
        $date->setTime($day_end, 0, 0);
        //get the timestamp of beginning
        $ending_timestamp = $date->format("U");

        //set the beginning of the day
        $date->setTime($day_begin, 0, 0);
        //get the timestamp of beginning
        $beginning_timestamp = $date->format("U");

        $day_length = $ending_timestamp - $beginning_timestamp;

        //60 seconds for 1min
        $interval = 60 * $event_interval;

        for($the_timestamp = 0; $the_timestamp <= $day_length ; $the_timestamp + $interval)
        {
            $current_timestamp = $beginning_timestamp + $the_timestamp;
            $date->setTimestamp($current_timestamp);
            $final_array[$current_date_year][$current_date_number . " " . $current_date_month][$current_timestamp] = $date->format("H : i");
        }

    }
}
```

the last "for" loop ends with an infinite loop and so reaches the maximum execution time, it must be done under 30s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is far too complex, you are doing something wrong. The following will generate an array representing a whole year:-

```
$start = new \DateTime('1st January');
$end = new \DateTime('31st December');
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end->modify('+ 1 day'));

$year = array();

foreach($period as $day){
    $year[$day->format('M')][(int)$day->format('d')] = $day->format('D');
}

var_dump($year);
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/9Qtca)

Comment: thanks a lot, i will adapt your way to my code. but what is the meaning of "P1D" and where can i find a documentation about that ? i search trough php.net but without result, it's like date formating letters ?

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/datetime and http://php.net/dateperiod and http://php.net/dateinterval

Answer (score 1):

```
for($the_timestamp = 0; $the_timestamp <= $day_length ; $the_timestamp + $interval){
    //Stuff
}
```

This loop doesn't increment `$the_timestamp` which is why it loops forever.

The last part should be `$the_timestamp += $interval` which is equivalent to `$the_timestamp = $the_timestamp + $interval`.